# Unable to share posts on my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I found yesterday the some of the [links](http://artcafe.bg/4-studio-apartamenta-pod-50-kv-m/) of my website I want to post, can't be posted on my Facebook page.

After some research and reading in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/, I found the some of the posts in my site are blocked but not all of them. 
I got this message:

> This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of
>   scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us
>   know.

and this also

> fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so
>   that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the
>   app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share
>   dialog. Otherwise, the default app id( 966242223397117 ) will be
>   assigned.

And website is clean doesn't indicate any virus ...ets.

Some of the post's are OK but other are blocked and I can't get idea what is the difference between them.

Also check my open graph meta tag's, they also looks Ok. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: did you fix it eventually? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

for the app_id issue:

Go to the following page: https://www.facebook.com/insights

Then use the "Create an App" and "Add your Domain" buttons to generate the app id for your site to be included in the meta tags on your web pages.

```html
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1234" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_app_id" />
```

Comment: Hi Vijay,
thank you for the response but nothing change i still got the same messages. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It started after I updated my Yoast plugin to the latest version.